# Extending Ionic2 and injecting ModalController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ng-modules

I am trying to develop a datepicker component that can be used for any project.

I have an NgModule that has components and I inject IonicModule in to it so it can use all the components/directives of ionic2.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(DatePickerModule)
    ],
    exports: [DatePickerComponent, DatePickerDirective],
    entryComponents: [DatePickerComponent],
    declarations: [DatePickerComponent, DatePickerDirective],
    providers: [DateService, nls]
})
export class DatePickerModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: DatePickerModule
        };
    }
};
```

One of the components injects ionic modal controller to display a modal.

```
export class MainDirective{
  public static config:any;
    constructor(private modalCtrl:ModalController) {
    }
    openModal() {
        this.modalCtrl.create(DatePickerComponent
        ).present();
    }
}
```

This NgModule is imported in to another App and from that app I am trying to call openModal.
This is how I import

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(App),
    DatePickerModule.forRoot(),
],
})
```

What happens is that it throws an error '_getPortal' of undefined from ionic-angular library.
I am guessing that it can't find the app to display to.

I am also guessing that I need to pass to forRoot the ACTUAL APP that will be working but I have no idea how to do this.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to extend specific components in ionic to indicate that my component was a modal of its own kind.

Injecting the modalcontroller in to a foreign component is too ineffecient and shouldn't be done in my opinion since your component isn't a modal.

For anything that is going to be displayed ViewController should be extended since this is the type of baseclass that is being displayed everytime you execute a present function.

A present function by proxy is a present function the app itself telling it to display said viewcontroller.

So to revise

Extend component to be a viewcontroller:

```
export class MyComponent extends ViewController
```

Inject the App in to your constructor

```
constructor(private _app:App){}
```

Display your new component on to the app

```
this.app.present(this);
```

Now the modal can be shown.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your answer? I am stuck with exactly the same problem. Am I understanding correctly that you basically made your own modal component? Do you have any pointers how to go about it?

Comment: Sure take a look https://github.com/misha130/ion-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/modal.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `forRoot` on the root module. This call sets up a bunch of application providers, which should only be done when bootstrapping Ionic. What you should do instead is just import `IonicModule` (no forRoot).

As for the `ModalController`, it's already provided when you import `IonicModule.forRoot` in the root module, so you don't need to worry about trying to add that. If you wanted to add it, you could, but it is dependent on the Ionic `App` which is only available when you bootstrap. So really, it's redundant to try to add it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process. I tried this and I still encountered the same problem my ngmodule can't find the app root where it should display the modal.